# table variable self reference in SQL server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, table-variable, self-reference

I found a very strange thing in SQL server. I am not sure it is normal.

```
insert @table
select ID, Lastname
from tableB
where ID NOT IN ( select ID from @Table)
```

It always says 0 row inserted.
If I use a physical table instead of @table, it works fine.

do I miss anything in my query?

Comment: please igore '' around @ because Stackoverflow doesn't allow it. Also it doesn't work with physical table either.

Comment: Add aliases for the tables and explicitly qualify the column names.  What happens then?

Comment: Sorry my mistake. DonorID NOT IN (select **CommunityID** from uAppealMembers) should be correct. solved.

Comment: Please put your code in the question, not in a comment. I tried to do it for you, but the formatting was completely lost. Please do it soon, or this will likely be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Since Table variable is scope specific like any other normal variable.So when you use it in any specific sql statement its scope is only that.Here as you say not in @tablevariable at this point of time it does not contain any data in it.Hence writing query like below:

```
INSERT INTO @table
select ID, Lastname from tableB where ID NOT IN ( select ID from @Table)
```

This query will never achieve what you are trying to achieve here.It always inserts all the records from tableB.